# Configuring C/C++ on eclipse on Fedora

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, fedora

I installed Eclipse in fedora and then installed the CDT plugin for developping C/C++ applications . All the installation are done !

So now i can create a C/C++ project but when it comes to running it  i got this message

**launch failed , Binary not found** 
  and
**unable to find full path to gcc**.

gcc -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o Rad1.o ../Rad1.c

Internal Builder: Cannot run program "gcc": Unknown reason

Error: Program "gcc" is not found in PATH

Is there any more configuration i must do so C/C++ runs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Executing c/c++ program with eclipse+unix base plate-forme, it requied object file of the program to execute/run it. So first of all you need to build your program by just pressing Ctr+b to buid it. This will create an object file that was required. Now you enabled to run/execute your programe. Good luck :)